# Cannot call function in the same class

Tags: node.js

I defined a class called `Plan`. Here is the code:

```
class Plan {
     async getPlanText(ctx) {
          return await this.getPlanDetails(ctx);
     }
     async getPlanDetails(ctx) {
          return ...
     }
}

exports.Plan = Plan;
```

I get:

> this.getPlanDetails is not a function

What I did wrong?

I used the `Plan` class in this way:

```
const { Plan } = require('./controllers/plan.controller');
let planController = new Plan(); 
console.log(planController.getPlanText('my context'));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show how your `getPlanText` function is being called.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn I added an example in the update

Comment: Can you try without adding `this` with `getPlanText`.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan yeah I tried with `this` and without  `this` and same problem..

Comment: Maybe you need to have the `function` keyword in declaration. Try `async function getPlanDetails(ctx)`

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan if I use this declaration I get the following error: `unexpected token a constructor method accessor or property was expected`

Comment: I tried ur code on a repl its wokring fine tho, https://repl.it/@pavanskipo/AgileTallMiddleware

Comment: @sfarzoso That's because a class aspects to have a constructor. You can have a look over [JS Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan I tried pavan demo and works for him, even without `constructor`, that's weird

Comment: @pavanskipo yes, I'm using `nodemon` too, I'm getting crazy about that

Comment: show us the error, as a picture i possible

Comment: @pavanskipo I added two screenshot, check please

Comment: @sfarzoso, what is that Bot error? any framework?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204932/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-pavan-skipo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. Basically you need to bind the function to a class while passing so it knows where to get the dependencies from. You can read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
const planController = new Plan();
const menu = new TelegraphInlineMenu(planController.getPlanText.bind(planController))
```

Comment: Really thanks, I've appreciated the effort of all you guys